# .net framework 4 on windows server 2008

Tags: windows, .net-4.0, windows-server-2008-r2

Ive got an issue, wich I just can not figure out how to fix. Ive got a pc with windows server 2008 and .net frameork 4.5 installed on it. Ive tried to run there appliction, that is running on .net framework 4.5, but it shows me an error .net framework 4 requied. Ive uninstalled NF4.5 and installed NF4 and.... the error is still there. Ive tried to compile a different application targetting .nf4(just a default informs project in VS) and it shows me the same error hen running on this PC. Searching gave me no results on this issue... Maybe somebody could help me?

Thank You very much for your attention and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution some time ago, but had no time to answer it here. As I found out it as windows server 2008 RC, not release version and .net framework 4 or 4.5 coul be installed on it, but it will never pass the check if it is installed. So? it is a bug, but only in RC version, that is not supported by microsoft quite a long time.